# Internal error: no current scope to add handler Push Notification Dialog to

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

Trying to add a XCTest UIInterruptionMonitor to b able to close system alerts such as Push Notification dialog during test. In my test case class ...

```
func closePushNotificationAlert()
{
    Autom.setup.addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "Push Notification Dialog")
    {
        (alert:XCUIElement) in
        alert.buttons["Allow"].tap()
        return true
    }
}
```

When I call this method when the PN dialog is open, it throws an exception...

> Assertion Failure: MyTest.swift:77: failed: caught
>   "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "Internal error: no current scope
>   to add handler Push Notification Dialog to."

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Or any other ways to close the system dialogs? It used to work in Xcode/XCTest 8 with simply checking for the element to exist in the app scope and tap these but that seems to be no-go in Xcode 9.

There must be some way to close these dialogs or else the whole XCUITest effort is a joke.

Comment: Please post more about the Autom.setup object.

Comment: Is the monitor registered before the alert appears?

Comment: @Oletha Yes but I noticed that the monitor definition cannot be in a method that is called by a test method. If I put it directly in a test method then the error doesn't occur.